# Error in json data using php json_encode for php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am saving data in php array in loop and then use json_encode function. Here is my code

```
foreach ($object_ids as $value) {
    $booking_data = array(
        'name' => $name, 
        'phone' => $phone, 
        'email' => $email,
    );
}
$booking_data = json_encode($booking_data,true);
print_r($booking_data);
```

and then is the result I got

```
{"name":"Peter ","phone":"03008000000","email":"peter@gmail.com"}{"name":"Jessica ","phone":"03038518000","email":"jesica@gmail.com"}{"name":"Anas ","phone":"03234152099","email":"anasiqbal1992@gmail.com"}{"name":"Anas ","phone":"03234152099","email":"anasiqbal1992@gmail.com"}
```

When I tried to beautify I get this error:

[image]

The comma is missing while encoding. Please let me know my mistake.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're doing here. First, this part...

```
$booking_data = array(
  'name' => $name, 
  'phone' => $phone, 
  'email' => $email,
);
```

... will rewrite the value of the same variable again and again - without actually encoding it (which happens outside of loop). As you're clearly getting some output, this looks more of a typo when trying to create a sample to post in SO though.

Second, this part:

```
print_r($booking_data)
```

... makes little sense, as result of json_encode is *string*, not an array.

---

What seems to happen there (according to the output you've shown) is that you actually add into some array results of `json_encoding` each individual associative array (with `name`, `phone` and `email` keys), then attempt to work with `print_r()` representation of that "array of JSONs". But that's not right: array of JSONs printed out with `print_r` doesn't give out a JSON!

Instead of doing all this, why don't you just create an array of arrays, then `json_encode` it once? Like this:

```
foreach ($object_ids as $value) {
    $booking_data[] = array(
        'name' => $name, 
        'phone' => $phone, 
        'email' => $email,
    );
}
echo json_encode($booking_data);
```

Comment: thank alot it works :) I am new here learning php and json. Thanks for the help.